# The pointer associated location in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning some pointer of C. Here is one homework I think the answer the teacher gave is wrong:

[image]

```
struct T {
    int *a;
    struct T* next;
};
int *y;
int **z;
struct T   x;
struct T*  p1;
struct T*  p2;
struct T** p3;

int main()
{  p1 = (struct T*) malloc(sizeof(struct T));
   p2 = &x ;
   y = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
   { int* a[3];
     a[1] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
     z = &a[1];        
     x.a  = *z;                     // point 1
     (*p1).a = *z;                  // point 2
   }             
   (*p1).next = p1;                 // point 3
   p2 = p1;                         // point 4
   p3 = &p1;                        // point 5
   p3 = *(&p3) ;                    // point 6
   p3 = &(*p3) ;                    // point 7
   x.a = y ;                        // point 8
   z = x.a ;                        // point 9
   free(x.a)                        // point 10
}
```

So the question is at point 2 what is the location associated with `*((*p1).next)`. The answer I was given is m7.2.
I think this is the location associated with `*(p1).next` not the one he is asking. And I think at point 2
`*((*p1).next)` is still undefined.

Comment: in this program you should learn how to do not. All the bad practices possible.

Comment: Tell your professor that casting the result of `malloc()` is not wise.

Comment: sizeof type is a bad practice

Comment: Ok, thank you, how about the question itself? Is my thought right?

Comment: @P__J__, why?  What's the problem with it?

Comment: `p1 -> next` (this the more correct way of dereferencing this pointer) at point two was never assigned and cannot be determined.

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't post the source rather than some obscure image?   It isn't just about SO's rules; it is almost never appropriate to paste text as an image, especially program text.

Comment: @DanielWalker It is error prone when you change the type of the object. if you use sizeof of the object you do not have to change anything. Search SO I have explained it in detail in one of my answers.

Comment: Post the code as text, not a pic.  More useful and easier to help.

Comment: You are wrong too. There is no such thing as `*p1.next`, which is entirely different from `(*p1).next`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, don't write code like this. Not even for demonstration purposes.

Members of pointers to structs can be accessed with `->`. `(*p1).a` is an obtuse way of writing `p1->a`. `*(*p1.next)` is an obtuse way of writing `*(p1->next)`.

---

At point 2, `p1->next` points at m7.2 which has not been initialized. It will contain garbage. Dereferencing it with `*(p1->next)` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: *`Not even for demonstration purposes.`* rather especially for

Comment: thank you, so does this mean that without initializing, p1->next is pointing to its own location?

Comment: @IsaacP.Liu No, m7.2 contains whatever was in that memory location when `malloc` grabbed it. Using `p1->next` is like using someone else's whiteboard without erasing it first. `p1->next = NULL` would initialize m7.2 to `NULL`.

Comment: @IsaacP.Liu it does point somewhere and this place is undefined. No one can say what this pointer contains.

Answer (score 4):

As you are learning C I will point some problems here:

1. In C we do not cast result of the malloc. The main reason is: it may suppress the warning id stdlib was not included and int size is smaller than the pointer size. It is rather historical problem (as modern compilers will warn about missing prototype) but it is still considered as a bad practice.
2. Do not use types in typedefs if you can use objects. `struct T *p1 = malloc(sizeof(*p1));` is a correct way. Using type is considered as bad practice.
3. When dereferencing pointers to structs or unions use `->` operator instead of `(*).`. It is easier for humans to read and instantly shows that we access members of the `struct` or `union` via the pointer.

Answering your main question: as the `p1 -> next` was never initialized, (assigned) it contains indeterminate value. This kind of pointers are called "wild pointers". You should never dereference wild pointers as it may lead to the Undefined Behaviour.